# Find all NaN slice in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, nan

I have a four dimensional Numpy ndarray (time, pressure level, latitude, longitude), and I want to check for each time and pressure level (dimensions 0 and 1) if there is an all-NaN slice along the latitude or longitude dimenstion (2 and 3).
I'd like to to it in a vectorized way, so without looping over the array, but I can't figure out how.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones([2,3,5,5])
a[0,2,:,2]=np.nan*np.ones_like(a[0,2,:,2])
a[0,1,1,:]=np.nan*np.ones_like(a[0,1,1,:])
a[0,0,1,2]=np.nan
a[1,1,:,2]=np.nan*np.ones_like(a[0,2,:,2])
a[1,1,1,:]=np.nan*np.ones_like(a[0,1,1,:])
print(a)
```

The array now holds ones (i.e. numbers), and in some locations slices of only `NaN`s. I'd like to know these locations. So in this case, I need to find that the `NaN` slices are at [0,2,:,2], [0,1,1,:], [1,1,:,2], and a[1,1,1,:].

Comment: Can you provide a code with example data and the desired results?

Comment: yes, one minute

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `np.isnan` function which creates a boolean matrix of the same size as your original matrix. Then just use boolean reduction operations like `np.all`. Thus the following code stores in *idx* the index of the lines (axis=1) of which all the elements are equal to `np.nan`.

```
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [1, np.nan, 1]])
arr_isnan = np.isnan(arr)
idx = np.argwhere(arr_isnan.all(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
>>>print(idx)
[[1]]
```

Following your example this methods gives you this output :

```
arr_isnan = np.isnan(a)
idx = np.argwhere(arr_isnan.all(axis=2))

>>>print(idx) #[0,2,:,2] and [1,1,:,2] because axis=2
array([[0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)

>>>print(a[idx[:,0], idx[:,1], :, idx[:,2]])
[[nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

So you just have to adjust the position of ":" according to the axis.